# Unable to move code from gitlab to github with history, commits and a large file

Tags: github, gitlab, git-lfs, repo

I am trying to move code from Gitlab to GitHub along with commits and a large file (142MB), but unable to do so. However, I was able to move code to GitHub from GitLab without history, and commits.
Can anyone suggest a fix?

```
$ git push github master
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (2/2), 265 MB | 23 MB/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 49, done.
Counting objects: 100% (49/49), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (34/34), done.
Writing objects: 100% (49/49), 278.93 MiB | 38.63 MiB/s, done.
Total 49 (delta 13), reused 42 (delta 11), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (13/13), done.
remote: error: Trace: df012bdf3866620fba543b---------------------------------
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File Manual.docx is 142.02 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File jar/abcbit.jar is 111.12 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To <<github_repository_url>>
![remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github_repository_url'
```

Comment: Are you ok with re-writing the commit history to un-track the large file(s) / migrate them to lfs?

Comment: Yes i am okay with that